# In Beamer cannot link/ref/hyperref to a certain slide/frame where a label was placed

Tags: beamer, hyperref, labels, nameref, pageref

This is the code I am using.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[breakwords]{truncate}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\hypersetup{
    pdfstartview={Fit},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    pdffitwindow=true,
    breaklinks=true,
    pdftitle={title},
    pdfauthor={author},
    pdfsubject={subject},
}

% \usetheme[dark]{tpu}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[style=iso]{datetime2}
\hypersetup{bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{bla bla bla}
\subtitle{othe bla}
\normalsize
\author{blaname blasurname}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\section{bla section 0}
\begin{frame}[fragile] 
    \frametitle{bla bla frame title 0}
    bla text 0
\end{frame}

\section{bla section 1}
\subsection{bla subsection} \label{blalabel1}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{bla bla frame title}
    bla bla text
    Go to slide \hyperref[blalabel2]{\pageref{blalabel2}: \nameref{blalabel2}} % <-------- This link
    Other way - Go to slide \hyperref[blalabel2]{\autoref{blalabel2}: \nameref{blalabel2}} % <-------- This link
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile] 
    \frametitle{bla bla frame title 2}
    bla text 2
\end{frame}

\subsection{bla subsection 2} \label{blalabel2} % <------- This destination frame/section/label
\begin{frame}[fragile] 
    \frametitle{bla bla frame title 3}
    bla text 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The link is created but when clicked it sends me to the first page of the document, not to the desired page.
Links in ToC work perfectly, when clicked they send me to the correct frame/page/slide/label location. The "problem" is only with normal (outside ToC) linking. How do I link (or maybe label) correctly to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: I cannot compile your code (assuming this is LaTeX, pdftex): **(1)** The theme `tpu` is not available on Overleaf. **(2)** the command `\titleframe` is unknown etc. Please make sure that you provide **only the relevant code** and remove everything else (but the code should be compilable without modification). In addition, the `hyperref` package should normally the **last package** that you load.

Comment: What happens if you place `\label{blalabel2}` inside the target `frame`?

Comment: I updated the sample code. Removed not related/blocking stuff and moved hyperref to be loaded as last. Now it should be compiling. The problem still persists...

I will check if your suggestion on label placing works. Thanks for now.

Comment: Placing the label like this `\begin{frame}[fragile] \label{blalabel1}` doesn't solve the issue.
Same for `\frametitle{bla bla frame title} \label{blalabel1}`.

Comment: Searching for a solution some hours ago, I saw another way of defining frames - title-ing and labeling was a bit different syntactically... 
It didn't solve the problem, in fact it did even give some compilation issues but it made me think there might be other ways of labeling/linking  (in Beamer) and maybe the way I am trying to do it isn't the correct one...

Comment: In document class 'book' or 'article', this linking to a label as `\hyperref[blalabel2]{\autoref{blalabel2} - \nameref{blalabel2}}` works perfectly fine.
In beamer, the same adapted as `\hyperref[blalabel2]{\pageref{blalabel2}: \nameref{blalabel2}}` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the label into the optional argument of the frame and then use \hyperlink. See the documentation of beamer, 11.1 Adding Hyperlinks and Buttons. It also describes how to target a specific slide.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames,table}, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[breakwords]{truncate}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\hypersetup{
    pdfstartview={Fit},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    pdffitwindow=true,
    pdftitle={title},
    pdfauthor={author},
    pdfsubject={subject},
    bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4
}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[style=iso]{datetime2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\hyphenpenalty=10000


\title{bla bla bla}
\subtitle{othe bla}
\normalsize
\author{blaname blasurname}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\section{bla section 0}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{bla bla frame title 0}
    bla text 0
\end{frame}

\section{bla section 1}
\subsection{bla subsection} 
\begin{frame}[fragile,]
    \frametitle{bla bla frame title}
    bla bla text
    Go to slide \hyperlink{blalabel2}{\pageref*{blalabel2}: \nameref*{blalabel2}} % <-------- This link
    Other way - Go to slide \hyperlink{blalabel2}{\autoref*{blalabel2}: \nameref*{blalabel2}} % <-------- This link
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{bla bla frame title 2}
    bla text 2
\end{frame}

\subsection{bla subsection 2}  
\begin{frame}[fragile,label=blalabel2]
    \frametitle{bla bla frame title 3}
    bla text 3
\end{frame}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It compiles correctly but when clicked, the link sends to the first/top frame, not where the label was set.

Comment: Did you try exactly my example?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. My bad. I did the label change but continued using /hyperref instead of of your indicated /hyperlink. Didn't notice it... (and didn't just copy paste all your code).
With /hyperlink (and 'new' labeling) it works perfectly. With /hyperref (as I were trying before) it didn't solve the issue. I am going to use /hyperlink 
 and the labeling as in documentation.
Thank you a lot for the great help. I am choosing your answer as the solution.